# how can I insert a decimal number using UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad format?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am developing a app, taking hotel name and price name so I am using UITextField for them, and when I am inserting price, I am using UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad, but unfortunately there is return key, no done key and no decimal key, because price can be like 15.22$, so what is solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use numbers & punctuation keyboard

```
textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

**EDIT:**

The UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad type only shows them, but is only available in 4.1 and later.

Comment: @KingOfBliss,     I want to use NumberPad, and I want to implement that, not this one Sir

Comment: Then you should design your own keyboard

Comment: thanx, I was also thinking same, well I do accept your answer because it is also one way to decimal input :-)

Comment: [link](http://blog.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/13/iphone-number-pad-with-a-decimal-point/)            see the and give me some idea, because I am new to iphone programming

Comment: create a viewcontroller named DecimalPointNumberPadViewController then in .h @interface DecimalPointNumberPadViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
     NumberKeypadDecimalPoint *numberKeyPad;
 }
 @end

Comment: in .m @implementation DecimalPointNumberPadViewController
 - (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     numberKeyPad = [[NumberKeypadDecimalPoint keypadForTextField:textField] retain];
 }
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     [numberKeyPad release];
 }
 @end

Comment: now on textfield begin editing resign the default keyboard and create a view to place this view controller

Comment: Check the sample code here http://blog.devedup.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/DecimalPointNumberPad-v4.zip

Comment: @KingOfBliss, I have seen the code, but how can I use this code in my code ?

Comment: add NumberKeypadDecimalPoint.h and NumberKeypadDecimalPoint.m file to your project

Comment: Create instance as NumberKeypadDecimalPoint *numberKeyPad; then assign property and synthesize it

Comment: Then implement the delegate methods as in DecimalPointNumberPadViewController.m

Comment: @KingOfBliss, let me do it Sir, I will tell U as I will do :-)

Comment: @veer: ok. and no need for use of "sir". :)

Comment: The UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad type only shows them, but is only available in 4.1 and later.